# How to add two lists together to make a list of lists?

Tags: python

If I have lists `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]` how can I make a list of lists `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`?

When I ran `a.append(b)` with `a = [1,1,1]` and `b = [1,2,4]` I got `[1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 4]]`

I would like `[[1,1,1],[2,2,4]]`

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
newlist=[a,b]
```

if `a=[1,2,3]` and `b=[4,5,6]`?

Comment: or if he actually wants to modify `a`, `a[:] = [a, b]`

Answer (score 0):

declare

```
a = [1,1,1]
b = [1,2,4]
c = []

c.append(a)
c.append(b)
```